# Beautifulsoup with selenium, How to get the second text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML code

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">
<div style="text-align:center; table-layout: fixed; font-size: 0;">
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">10</div>
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">9/div>
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">7</div>
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">2</div>
</div>
</td>
```

My code

```
td_list = perform.tbody.find_all("td")
section1 = td_list[9].text.strip() # .strip skip my first element space like \n\n 10
```

Out my result:
10                              \n\n 9                          \n\n7                  \n\n2

There are four text in above html code. I want get it each of elements from text.
I want to get only 10 & only 2 for my code
How do I supposed to do?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to get each of the elements, then you say you want to get only 10 & 2. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want first and last text from the `<td>` you can use list index `[0]` and `[-1]` respectively. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<td style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">
<div style="text-align:center; table-layout: fixed; font-size: 0;">
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">10</div>
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">9</div>
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">7</div>
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: text-top; width:16px; height:16px; display:inline-block; font-size: 12px;">2</div>
</div>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

td = soup.select_one("td")
text = td.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n").split("\n")
print(text[0])
print(text[-1])
```

Prints:

```
10
2
```